# notifyDataSetChanged is not working inside DialogFragment

Tags: android, custom-lists, notifydatasetchanged

I'm really stuck in this problem for 2 days, my problem is i have a dialog `Fragment` inside my `ArrayAdapter` class which have a button that call an `AsyncTask` in this `Adapter` class, and at the end of the `AsyncTask` i'm changing list data and call `notifayDataSetChanged` but it's not working, it works only outside the `DialogFragment`, it's not even call `getView()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method from **onPostExecute(..)** of your **AsyncTask(..)**

```
public void onReturnWebService(boolean status) {
    if (status) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

You may put this line of code **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** on **UiThread**

Comment: i tried this : @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result); getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override
      public void run() { flagsLikes.set(position, "true");listObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
     }); } but it's not working